# How can I run repeated measure ANCOVA in r?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, ancova

I originally performed 2x2 repeated measure ANOVA using a dataset. There were two independent variables, within factors (foot position and limbs), and the single-leg jump heights were measured. For this statistical analysis, I used the following code in R:

```
model <- aov(JumpHeight ~ Limb*Condition+Error(ID/(Limb+Condition)), data = single)
```

Where ***ID*** is each participant number and ***Condition*** is the foot position. However, one of my co-authors wanted to check what the result looks like if we run ANCOVA with ***the lean mass of each limb as a covariate***. So, I have attempted to run ANCOVA with this dataset, but I am not sure I am correctly doing the analysis. Here is my code for the analysis:

```
model <- aov(JumpHeight ~ Limb*Condition+LeanMass+Error(ID/(Limb+Condition)), data = single)
```

Or should I consider the limb as a between factor like the following code?

```
model <- aov(JumpHeight ~ Limb*Condition+LeanMass+Error(ID/Condition), data = single)
```

If so, how do I report the results on the paper based on the output below?

```
> model <- aov(JumpHeight~Limb*Condition+LeanMass+Error(ID/Condition), data = single)
> summary(model)

Error: ID
               Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Limb            1 0.001577 0.001577   0.719 0.4247  
Condition       1 0.002297 0.002297   1.046 0.3404  
LeanMass        1 0.011955 0.011955   5.445 0.0523 .
Limb:Condition  1 0.000124 0.000124   0.056 0.8190  
Residuals       7 0.015368 0.002195                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: ID:Condition
               Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Limb            1 0.0002711 0.0002711   1.752 0.2222  
Condition       1 0.0013059 0.0013059   8.439 0.0197 *
LeanMass        1 0.0000044 0.0000044   0.028 0.8709  
Limb:Condition  1 0.0000002 0.0000002   0.001 0.9701  
Residuals       8 0.0012380 0.0001547                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Within
               Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Limb            1 1.083e-04 1.083e-04   5.066 0.0423 *
LeanMass        1 1.163e-04 1.163e-04   5.443 0.0364 *
Limb:Condition  1 2.400e-07 2.400e-07   0.011 0.9166  
Residuals      13 2.779e-04 2.137e-05                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

---

***Updated***

I have figured out the correct code to run 2x2 repeated measure ANCOVA with the help of @Billy and attached the result below.

```
> m <- aov(JumpHeight~Limb*Condition+LeanMass+Error(ID/(Limb*Condition)), data = single)
> summary(m)

Error: ID
          Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
LeanMass   1 0.005401 0.005401   1.703  0.228
Residuals  8 0.025373 0.003172               

Error: ID:Limb
          Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Limb       1 0.0002906 2.906e-04   8.972 0.0172 *
LeanMass   1 0.0001263 1.263e-04   3.899 0.0838 .
Residuals  8 0.0002591 3.239e-05                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: ID:Condition
          Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Condition  1 0.001095 0.0010955   7.991 0.0198 *
Residuals  9 0.001234 0.0001371                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: ID:Limb:Condition
               Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Limb:Condition  1 1.780e-06 1.781e-06   0.099   0.76
Residuals       9 1.618e-04 1.798e-05
```

Comment: @YoungminChun, try looking over this page for some help on the specification: https://www.statmethods.net/stats/anova.html. As far as the random effects go, I can't tell whether ID is nested within "Limb" and "Condition" or just "Condition". If the participants were tested on each limb in each condition, then you need both in the "error()" declaration. As far as specifying the covariate, adding "LeanMass" does add a fixed effect for that variable as desired.

Comment: @Billy Thank you for your comment. I tried to include "Limb" in the "error" declaration because participants' both limbs were tested in each condition, but R returned a warning message as follows: 
`> m <- aov(jump_ht~Limb*Condition+Lean+Error(ID/(Limb+Condition)), data = single)
Warning message:
In aov(jump_ht ~ Limb * Condition + Lean + Error(ID/(Limb + Condition)),  :
  Error() model is singular` Can I just ignore that? The R looks like returning the result anyway.

Comment: it sounds like your design is fully crossed, which requires interactions. The fact that the model is singular cannot be ignored: the model is not able to estimate the error term. Correcting the syntax may or may not help, depending on your sample size. Try this instead: m <- aov(jump_ht ~ Limb*Condition*Lean + Error(ID/(Limb*Condition)), data = single)

Comment: @Billy I tried to include the interaction in Error declaration with the code that you suggested above, but it returned the same warning message. The sample size of this dataset is only 11. Is it possible that the small sample size caused this warning message?

Comment: My guess would be yes in this case. Singularity in this case would potentially mean that you're missing a between-person condition observation for at least one person. You would also want to confirm that no between-subject condition is included in the error term. If those criteria are met, then you may consider moving this to a linear mixed model using the nlme or lme4 packages to see if the model will fit under that slightly different specification.

Comment: @Billy Oh thank you! I just figured out why I got the warning message. As you pointed out, some of my data was missed because the code was mixed up with the previous analysis. Once I fixed the code, it worked well. I have attached the result above. Could you please let me know how to interpret this result? Also, I was wondering if the covariate shouldn't be included with the interaction (i.e., m <- aov(jump_ht~Limb*Condition*Lean+Error(ID/(Limb*Condition)), data = single)) because the result looks like not including the covariate in the comparison of "condition" and "interaction" for me.

Comment: Looks like you have a main effect for both limb and condition without a significant interaction between the two. Seems like post hocs (assuming any of those factors has more than 2 levels) and visualizations of the effects would be the next step here to make sense of what is being shown in the tables